# Update an edittext inside a dialog, value gets updated but not the text

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a edittext which I am displaying inside a dialog, but later (before the dialog is closed) I am updating the value inside it but when I do this I can read the correct new value from .gettext() but the edittext is still empty, why?

This is my code:

```
public void setText(String url) {
    response.setText("http://xxxx/" + url);
    response.invalidate();
    response.selectAll();
}
```

It feels like I've tried everything, searched for hours for a answer but nothing that I've tried has worked. :(

Is there any quick solution to this problem or do I really need to redraw the whole custom dialog?

Comment: anyone pretty please? :(

Comment: I can do it later when I come home :)

Comment: Are you sure the text color is not transparent? :) ..add the code where you create the dialog and set text

Comment: @cubsink are you calling settext() in an event listener (like onDialogClosed() or onClick()) ?

Comment: Still you are not home? Code please sir,

Comment: Are there any errors on log cat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look simply,

It all works fine,

```
    EditText input;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        input = new EditText(this); 

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
        alertDialog.setTitle("Title"); 
        alertDialog.setMessage("Message"); 
        alertDialog.setView(input, 10, 0, 10, 0); // 10 spacing, left and right 

        alertDialog.show(); 

        input.setText("Raja");
        setText("Hindustani");

    }

    public void setText(String url) { 
        input.setText("http://xxxx/" + url); 
        input.invalidate(); 
        input.selectAll(); 
    }
```

This set of code works completely fine..there is no problem in there..Check it again.

You need to put your complete code here to let us know how you get this problem.

Comment: I will put my complete code here when I get home, because it doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change TextView's text from a separate thread after some task is done, then you should use Handler, otherwise you might face weird errors.

```
EditText input;
Thread myWorkerThread;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Handler successHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message)
    {
        setText("Success Message");
    }
};

public void setText(String url)
{
    input.setText("http://xxxx/" + url);
    input.invalidate();
    input.selectAll();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    input = new EditText(this);

    myWorkerThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // do your tasks here

            // after task is done, call the handler
            successHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };
}
```

Now before starting myWokerThread show your alertdialog.

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
alertDialog.setView(input, 10, 0, 10, 0); // 10 spacing, left and right
alertDialog.show();
myWorkerThread.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
alertDialog.setTitle("Title"); 
alertDialog.setMessage("Message"); 

EditText input = new EditText(YourActivity.this);
input.setText("NAME");

alertDialog.setView(input, 10, 0, 10, 0); // 10 spacing, left and right 
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      //some_string_instance = input.getText().toString();
   }
});
alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

   }
});

alertDialog.show();
```

You can use alert dialog with two buttons and and on positive button click you save the value of edittext to some string variable and can use it later in your code... say your method is setText(some_string_instance)..

Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html)

Comment: Congrates Bro..just seen your answers and profile..you are amazing..and wvery sporty in 36 days given 446 answers and earned 4k repo..you really rock..It will be nice if you got time you come to chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people and share your knowledge there too. Once Again will have to say..Good Participation...